Best way to add custom fields in a standard object and push the update to all users to existing managed package
We have a requirement to enhance the Task object and layout with some additional Custom Fields.
Our package is on AppExchange already and consumed by many orgs, so this is meant to be an update. The goal is to add the new fields without breaking any of the existing functionality that the customers may have (eg after their manual layout changes or additional ApEx packages etc).
I made that possible for some scratch orgs through changes in the package.xml, custom objects, the Admin.profile-meta.xml and Task-Task Layout.layout-meta.xml, however this can't be expected to work for the myriads of different orgs that our customers have. Running sf project deploy start will fail if there are conflicts, and creating and installing a beta package also fails for the same reasons, which is expected.
I've seen all around mentions about the Metadata API, about the Tooling API and SOAP and REST and Apex classes and I'm lost.
What's the best way to do this in 2024 for a managed package?

Can I include the xml files for the custom object in the package, and programmatically with Apex and post-install scripts create and assign permission sets and change the layout of Task?
Can I include an Apex class that does all of the above instead? Eg by calling a REST API.
Can I use my JavaScript client app that is running embedded in our customers' Salesforce orgs to do the same (eg upon initialisation, "if Task.Foo_Field__c doesn't exist, create it") ?
I just discovered the UI API, is this maybe a better alternative?

This question: Add custom fields after a managed package is released is quite close to what I want to do, but is also somewhat unanswered.
